# Is there some way to duplicate the image between a UHD display and an FHD display without compromising the UHD resolution?

Tags: windows-7, linux, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a TV and a Monitor both hooked up to the same computer. I sometimes like to play games on my sofa on the TV, and for this purpose I have a keyboard, mouse and controller (everything) in front of the TV as well as on my desk.

I used to have a fullhd monitor and what I would do was duplicate the output so both the screens displayed the same image. Recently I upgraded to a UHD monitor and now if I want to duplicate the output it will (at least on windows) force my UHD monitor to use FHD (1920x1080) resolution instead of it's native UHD (3840x2160) resolution.

Is there some way I can keep my UHD display at it's native resolution and duplicate the output over to the FHD TV at the TV's native (downscaled) resolution?

I have an Nvidia GPU, and I am using Windows (7), I would however also like to know if it is possible and (if so) how to do this on X11 and Wayland on Linux as well.

Comment: According to this: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3035478/forcing-duplicate-monitors-resolutions.html you can achieve this on windows with AMD cards by enabling scaling on the GPU instead of on the Display, this does not ifx the problem for nvidia cards however.

Comment: I found out that you can use DSR (dynamic super resolution) to up the resolution of your FHD to UHD by setting it to "4x" resolution if the displays are extended; but this option is sadly not available for duplicate displays.